# Pass A react component to leaflet popup

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am using leaflet in my react code and I am not using react-leaflet. I want to pass a react component or jsx code to binbPopup function to every tooltip.

```
let marker = new L.marker(...).bindPopup(<div>Hi</div>)
```

bindPopup gets string as a input so I cannot use jsx. I also tried to use react portals but still it doesn't work.
What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) method of `ReactDOMServer` to convert React component to markup string.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "./styles.css";

const CustomReactPopup = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "black" }}>
      <p>A pretty React Popup</p>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    var map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09])
      .addTo(map)
      .bindPopup(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomReactPopup />))
      .openPopup();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="map" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-with-react-znk11

Comment: I have tried it. My component is connected to redux and I get an error like below: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Component)".

Comment: @HadiRanjbar Can you update your question with relevant code?

Comment: The code is exactly like yours. The only different is that CustomReactPopup is connected to redux and renderToString or render methods create a new react tree that is not has redux provider.

Comment: @HadiRanjbar were you able to solve it? i am also facing the same issue when using redux

Comment: React Docs do not recommend using renderToString on the client-side, see https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code:~:text=not%20support%20streams.-,Removing%20renderToString%20from%20the%20client%20code,-Sometimes%2C%20renderToString

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` in the client side is not recommended, as it significantly increases the app bundle size, see [React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code).

Therefore, the best way to get the HTML string equivalent of a component is:

> use `createRoot` and read HTML from the DOM

```js
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

const popup = (<div>...</div>);

let marker = new L.marker(...).bindPopup(() => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const root = createRoot(div);
    flushSync(() => {
       root.render(popup);
    });
    return div.innerHTML;
});
```